# Can you use IIS DIPR on a Point-To-Site configured Azure Website?

Tags: networking, azure-web-app-service, azure-virtual-network, azure-app-service-plans

We have the following infrastructure in Azure:

```
api-gateway.example.com (frontend API gateway) 
api-1.example.com (microservice API) 
api-2.example.com (microservice API) 
db.example.com (VM running SQL Server)
```

The DB is in a Virtual Network. We connect to it from the API's via a Point-To-Site VPN using Dynamic Gateway, via it's local IP address (e.g 10.1.1.1)

Now, we'd like to use [DIPR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/using-dynamic-ip-restrictions) on the microservice API's to restrict access to the public, and only allow traffic from the API gateway.

Problem is - how do we know what the internal IP of the API gateway is? Since it's not actually *in* the VNET?

From reading - it appears the only way to lock down an Azure Website from public/internet access is to place it in [Azure App Service Environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-app-service-environment-intro) (too costly for us)

Comment: It seems we couldn't use application gateway to transfer app service directly. As you say, the right way is using ASE.

Answer (score 0):

> Problem is - how do we know what the internal IP of the API gateway is

As I know, we can only get public IP at currently.

We usually need to protect our SQL Database in Azure virtual network. We can use [Network Security group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-nsg) to deny traffic to resources connect to Azure virtual network. 
If you want to protect your on-premise API app. We can set authentication. Or set [IP security](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/ipsecurity) in Web.config